# appium fails to launch on iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6, appium

I have the latest version of appium (1.4.0) on a mac. I'm trying to use the element inspector on an app. So, I tried to launch the app through my device but I keep getting an error saying could not initialize ideviceinstaller. So, I tried running it on the simulator. But, the app keeps crashing and i get the log message that DYShaderAnalyzerNextGPU is implemented in two locations. Then, a WebKit threading error and finally that Instruments exited with code 253.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a few things..

First, did you install ideviceinstaller? 
if you have homebrew installed, you can install it with `brew install ideviceinstaller`

Second, the error you're seeing with `DYShaderAnalyzerNextGPU` can be caused when the `DYShaderAnalyzerNextGPU` class is a member of multiple targets in a single app. Does your project contain multiple targets? Is this file a member of both? You can still build/run the app relatively safely with this error, but it would be good practice to organize the project such that `DYShaderAnalyzerNextGPU` only needs to belong to one target.

Third, does your app run successfully in the simulator at all? If you're trying to do special graphics work inside WebKit, it is possible that you need to be running on a real device. Also, you should not attempt to manipulate what thread WebKit is using, I think it typically wants to be the main thread.